# Prometheus is throwing a "server returned HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, spring-boot-actuator, prometheus-operator

In multimaven module project when i tried to access prometheus form actuator it's throwing Internal Server Error but able to access actuator properly.

added following dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Micormeter core dependecy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Micrometer Prometheus registry -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

also added in application.properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

I am stuck in this.

[image]